# How do I reset the turtle's orientation without resetting the colour?(python turtle)

Tags: python, python-turtle

I'm working on a simple racing project where 4 turtles race on a track and at the finish line when it starts lap 2, it goes forward 1 to exit the point where it counts the lap. For some reason, the turtle's orientation is ever so slightly off 0 degrees, therefore the int() function rounds it to 0 and re-counts the lap. If I use the reset() function, it resets the colour.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `turtle.setheading(0)` to reset the turtle to the original orientation.